# How to loop this code back to the beginning?

Tags: python, loops

Could anyone help me with looping this code back to the beginning if the user inputs yes and ending the program if the user inputs no?

```
while True:
    print ("Hello, this is a program to check if a word is a palindrome or not.")
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    word = word.casefold()
    revword = reversed(word)
    if list(word) == list(revword):
        print ("The word" ,word, "is a palindrome.")
    else:
        print("The word" ,word, "is not a palindrome.")
    print ("Would you like to check another word?")
    ans = input()
    if ans == ("Yes") :
      #here to return to beginning
    else ans == ("No"):
        print ("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use continue to continue your loop and break to exit it.

```
   if ans == ("Yes") :
      continue
    else ans == ("No"):
        print ("Goodbye")
        break
```

Or, you could just leave off the `if ans == ("Yes")` and just have this:

```
    else ans == ("No"):
        print ("Goodbye")
        break
```

Or even better, you could change your while loop to check the `ans` variable instead of doing `while True:`

Answer (score 1):

Change `while True` to while `ans == "Yes"`.  Before the loop, you have to define `ans` as "Yes" (`ans = "Yes`).  That way, it will automatically run once, but will prompt the user to continue.

Alternatively, you could do this

```
ans = input()
if ans == "No":
    break
```

Comment: thanks i tried changing the start to while ans == "Yes" but is will not run, it says it "expected an intended block"?

Comment: Your while true loop isn't indented correctly. The while loop body has to be indented